# How to disable horizontal scrolling when programmatically adding buttons to UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am learning how to use UIScrollView and I am adding some buttons to test. However, I find that whenever I add a button, no matter how small or where I place it in my view, it causes a large amount of horizontal scrolling. Here is my relavent code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 3000)];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:@"Cool title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFav) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_scroller addSubview:btn];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

So, even if the button appears to just be on the top left corner of my view, I have a bunch of scrolling white space to the right of the button, but I don't want any horizontal scrolling at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content size of the UIScrollView to 640.  If this is for the iPhone you probably want 320.  Better yet, set the content size width to be the same width as your UIScrollView width.

```
[_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scroller.size.width, 3000)];
```

You probably also want your UIScrollView to have the same width as your view controller.